# JSON object null in browser but not firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

When I step through this javascript code (scoreboard.js) in firebug, it works fine with the alerts. When I don't put a line break in firebug and just run it normally, I received a "favs is null" message (no alerts).

```
var favs = $.getJSON("favs.json");
favs = $.parseJSON(favs.responseText);
favs = favs.myTeams;

for (i=0; i<favs.length; i++){
    alert(favs[i].text);
}
```

The JSON (favs.json)

```
{"myTeams":[{"sport":10,"id":10,"abbrev":"NYY","isFav":false,"text":"New York  Yankees","sw_abbrev":"nyy"},{"sport":28,"id":19,"abbrev":"nyg","isFav":false,"text":"New York Giants","sw_abbrev":"nyg"},{"sport":46,"id":18,"abbrev":"NY","isFav":false,"text":"New York Knicks","sw_abbrev":"nyk"},{"sport":90,"id":11,"abbrev":"NJ","isFav":false,"text":"New Jersey Devils","sw_abbrev":"njd"},{"sport":41,"id":2507,"abbrev":"PROV","isFav":false,"text":"Providence Friars"},{"sport":46,"id":17,"abbrev":"NJ","isFav":false,"text":"New Jersey Nets","sw_abbrev":"njn"},{"sport":600,"id":363,"abbrev":"Blues","isFav":false,"text":"Chelsea","sw_abbrev":"ENG.CHELSEA","isNational":false}]}
```

The HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scoreboard.js"></script>        
</head>

<body>
    Test
</body>
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to

```
favs = $.parseJSON(favs.responseText);
```

And I'm pretty sure `$.getJSON()` doesn't return the json, but returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jqxhr-object).

Looking at the documentation for [parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), you should probably be doing:

> jQuery.getJSON( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] )

```
$.getJSON("favs.json",
          function(json)
{
  var favs = json.myTeams;  

  for (i=0; i<favs.length; i++){  
    alert(favs[i].text);  
  }  
});
```

`$.getJSON()` - The success callback (in my example is the anonymous function) is passed the returned data, which is typically a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the $.parseJSON() method.

Comment: The $.getJSON method would return the json as the first argument of the success function.

Answer (score 2):

$.getJSON expects a success callback.  This should work:

```
$.getJSON('favs.json', function (data) {
    favs = data.myTeams;

    for (i=0; i<favs.length; i++){
        alert(favs[i].text);
    }
});
```

The reason that you were seeing that it works fine when stepping through the code is probably because you gave the asynchronous call time to complete.

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous.  This means it runs in the background, so the the lines after `$.getJSON` are called before the JSON is retrieved.

You should put all code dealing with the JSON inside the callback.

(P.S. `$.parseJSON` is not needed.  `$.getJSON` does that for you).

```
$.getJSON("favs.json", function(favs){
    favs = favs.myTeams;

    for (i=0; i<favs.length; i++){
        alert(favs[i].text);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the first line:

```
var favs = $.getJSON("favs.json");
```

The getJSON() method is asynchronous. I.e. it takes time for the response to come back from the server, and javascript doesn't sit and wait for that before running the rest of your code.

You need to use a callback function, which executes once the response comes back:

```
var favs = null;
$.getJSON("favs.json", function(data) {
    // data is what the server returned
    // now you can do stuff with it
    favs = data.myTeams;

    // the rest of your code goes here
})
```

Comment: Remove `var favs = null;`.  The data should only be accessed in the callback; it should be a local variable, not global.  Also remove `$.parseJSON(data);`, the data is parsed for you by `$.getJSON`.

Comment: True about `$.parseJSON`. Perhaps true about `favs`, except we don't know the larger context of this. Perhaps there are other asynchronous functions further down that use `favs`, say, on click.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a race condition to me. The getJson function takes a onSuccess param that will be called when the data has been loaded. If you move your other lines into that function you should be good.

There are some excellent examples of this on the doc link below. The code I am posting here is for more of an example display based on this info you provided.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Something along the lines of:

```
var favs = $.getJSON("favs.json", function(data) {
    favs = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
    favs = favs.myTeams;

    for (i=0; i<favs.length; i++){
        alert(favs[i].text);
    }
} );
```

Comment: Remove `$.parseJSON(data.responseText);`.  That's wrong.  `data` will be parsed for you (and therefore there is no `responseText` property).

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "race condition", as there is no "timing" here.  The lines after `$.getJSON` are ran before the data is returned from the server, there's no way around that.